# Replace a > with a " sed regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have lots of files that have lines that are in the following way:

```
#include "3rd-party/*lots folders*>
```

problem is that it ends with `>` instead of `"`

Is there a quick regex for sed to change that?

basically, if the line starts with `#include "3rd-party`, it should replace the last character to `"`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
sed -i '' '/^[[:blank:]]*#include "3rd-party/s/>$/"/' file

#include "3rd-party/*lots folders*"
```

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` is not a character class which is understood by `sed`.

Comment: That's not correct, I've tested it with OSX `sed` and `gnu sed` and it worked.

Comment: Then it is a hidden "feature". Following the man page it should be `[[:space:]]`

Comment: Yes we can also use `[[:space:]]` but that also matches newline (though it would be fine in this current context).

Comment: Ok, POSIX defines `[[:blank:]]`, I see. I have the bad habit to look in the manual page of `grep` when searching for `sed` regular expression things.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can use:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*#include "3rd-party/s/>[[:space:]]*$/"/' file
```

Explanation:

- `/^[[:space:]]*#include/` is an address, a regular expression address. The subsequent command will apply to lines which start which optional space followed by an `#include` statement.
- `s/>[[:space:]]*$/"/` replaces `>` followed by optional space and the end of the line by a `"`.

Use the `-i` option if you want to change the file *in place*:

```
sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*#include/s/>[[:space:]]*$/"/' file
```

---

On a bunch of, let's say `C` files, use `find` and it's `-exec` option:

```
find . -name '*.c' -exec sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*#include/s/[[:space:]]*$/"/' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` for searching a pattern and doing an action on this line like

```
sed '/search_pattern/{action}' your_file
```

The action you want to do is replacing the last character in a line with `>$` where `>` is your desired character and `$` means that the searched character must be placed at the end of a line.

The action for doing this is the `sed`command `s///` which work's like `s/search_pattern/replace_pattern/`.

This looks for your goal like:

```
sed '/#include "3rd-party/{s/>$/"/}' your_file
```

But since `sed` is a (s)tream (ed)itor you have to use sed's command flag `-i` to make your changes inline or pipe it with `>` to a new file.

Like this

```
sed -i '/#include "3rd-party/{s/>$/"/}' your_file
```

or like this

```
sed '/#include "3rd-party/{s/>$/"/}' your_file > new_file
```

Please let me know if this does your work.